# Uitableviewcell content is not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a newbie iOS developer writing my apps in Objective-C language. I found myself facing a problem, and I searched a lot, but without results :(

The problem is: I'm programmatically populating uitable view cells with an image, an "eyelet" and a title, parsed from a news xml grabbed online.

The code I'm going to past here under make the UI snaps, but I already found the cause and I'm working on the solution, so no problem about this, the fact is that this code load the contents, but when I try to open a second view controller with a news detail I previously made...well...the cells aren't clickable!

Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        UILabel *eyeletLabel, *newsTitleLabel, *dateLabel;
        eyeletLabel = [UILabel new];
        newsTitleLabel = [UILabel new];
        newsImage = [UIImageView new];


    if (cell == nil) {
        //NSLog(@"Cell: %@", cell);
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        ATNews *thisNews = gNewsArray[indexPath.row];

        eyeletLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        eyeletLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        eyeletLabel.frame = CGRectMake(90.0f, 5.0f, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 20, 20);
        eyeletLabel.text = thisNews.eyelet;
        eyeletLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

        newsTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        newsTitleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        newsTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(90.0f, 20.0f, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 50, 50);

        newsTitleLabel.text = thisNews.title;
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        NSString *newDate = [formatter stringFromDate:thisNews.pubDate];
        dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithString:newDate];

        for (id obj in thisNews.newsPhotos) {
            NSUInteger counter = 0;
            if ([obj isEqualToString: @"true"]) {
                counter = counter + 2;

                imageUrlFromArray = [thisNews.newsPhotos objectAtIndex:counter];
                NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlFromArray];
                imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            }
            counter = counter + 3;
        }

        newsImage.frame = CGRectMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 70.0f, 70.0f);

        if (thisNews.newsPhotos.count != 0) {
            newsImage.image = nil;
            newsImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            newsImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            newsImage.layer.cornerRadius = newsImage.frame.size.width / 2;
            [newsImage.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        }
        else {

            newsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.png"];
            newsImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            newsImage.layer.cornerRadius = newsImage.frame.size.width / 2;
            [newsImage.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        }

         [cell addSubview:newsImage];

         [cell addSubview:eyeletLabel];
         [cell addSubview:newsTitleLabel];
         [cell addSubview:dateLabel];
    }
    else {
    //NSLog(@"Cell");
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

I searched for the solution a lot, I also read some similar question in here too, but without success, could you help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Now that it is clickable, you need to either add a segue from your cell to your new view controller or from your view controller create a segue to the new view controller and call

```
[self.viewcontroller performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your Identifer"];
```

Comment: mmm....interesting....I implemented it with a single testing-purpose NSLog and I noticed that cell responds to click with the logging I inserted in the method you suggested me. Now the point is that I've got to search to find how to load the viewcontroller from the storyboard, with the class I wrote and that's controlling it. In this class I implemented the prepareforSegue method, to pass some data to the destination controller. I'll search for the way to load it.Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thats great! If that solved your clicking problem be sure to accept! As for your next question I will edit my answer for you

Comment: Yay! It works! :) Thank you very much! Buuut....should I.......be sure to accept....what? Sorry, I don't get it! :)

Comment: haha Im glad it works!! Make sure you accept my answer as the correct answer:) Them little arrows Upclick it:)

Comment: Did it! I'm a stackoverflow newbie too, think I'm going to take tour to learn how to use it! Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you! And no problem at all!